# Unable to install ROS Groovy on Raspberry Pi

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, raspbian, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I'm currently trying to install ROS on my Raspberry Pi, I just followed the instruction on http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Raspbian and got some errors, error 404 server not found, when I do some researching, I found out that the instruction is outdated.

for information, I've install Raspbian from NOOBs for my Raspberry Pi an running on Raspberry Pi Type B

anyone could help ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/130671/unable-to-install-ros-groovy-on-raspberry-pi/) by [WMHanif](https://answers.ros.org/users/12081/wmhanif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-18**:
A quick glance suggests that the repository still exists, and should probably still work. Can you add the exact command and error you're seeing to your question?

**Comment by [WMHanif](https://answers.ros.org/users/12081/wmhanif/) on 2014-02-18**:
when I reload apt sources, I got this error:

Err http://ros.raspbian.org wheezy/main armhf Packages
404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ros.raspbian.org/repo/ros/dists/wheezy/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the repository at ros.raspbian.org is no more. Try removing that line from your sources and using the builds for raspbian that are located in http://64.91.227.57/repos/rospbian instead.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [WMHanif](https://answers.ros.org/users/12081/wmhanif/) on 2014-02-19**:
how to remove that line because the line reloads itself when I execute the "sudo apt-get update" command

**Comment by [mistrysiddh](https://answers.ros.org/users/74987/mistrysiddh/) on 2021-12-07**:
I tried to replace it with it but still not working

```
404! PAGE NOT FOUND
```